# Sorting images issue ( Magento 2.4.3

Tags: sorting, magento2.4.3

I face an issue when upload images bulky that i don`t have the way to sort it as i want , it is sorted random , even if i one of it as base,small,thumbnail
Need the way to know how to sort it for example
[image: Sorting iamge]

Comment: you can simple drag the image and place it in any order
https://vimeo.com/764419294/32f84eb4ea